# Repairing a failed Debian upgrade

Tags: debian, systemd, upgrade, sysvinit

I was attempting to upgrade from debian 9 to 10 but the installation failed when attempting to install `systemd-sysv_241-7~deb10u6_amd64.deb`.  I get the following error:

My attempts to run `apt --fix-broken install` have not been successful and lead to the same error below.

```
(Reading database ... 59371 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd-sysv_241-7~deb10u6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-sysv (241-7~deb10u6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd-sysv_241-7~deb10u6_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/halt.8.gz', which is also in package sysvinit 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd-sysv_241-7~deb10u6_amd64.deb
```

In my attempts to isolate, I get the following when I run the failed command in verbose mode:

```
# dpkg --debug=77777 -i /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd-sysv_241-7~deb10u6_amd64.deb
...
D000040: ok 2 msgs >><<
D010000: check_triggers_cycle pnow=man-db:amd64
D020000: check_triggers_cycle pnow=man-db:amd64 first
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/man-db.postinst ( triggered /usr/share/man )
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
D020000: post_postinst_tasks - trig_incorporate
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd-sysv_241-7~deb10u6_amd64.deb
```

Unfortunately, this 'verbose' debugging is too terse for me and I am stuck mid-upgrade.

I tried running the man-db post install as follows:

```
sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/man-db.postinst configure 2.6.7.1-2
```

and it completed successfully without error so I am unsure what the error is to be able to try and fix.

I know that the installation scripts are located in `ls /var/lib/dpkg/info`, but I do not know which are related to this package.

Can anyone tell me where to get more detail to debug this more thoroughly and fix it?

Answer (score 12):

I don't see how you could get more relevant information than you already have.
The error message says:

> trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/halt.8.gz', which is also in package sysvinit 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1

this is basically it: two packages want to install the same file, and debian forbids this (as a single file cannot have two different contents).

Since the file in question is only a manpage, there shouldn't be any *real* problem (as in: catastrophic problem that leads to an unbootable system), regardless which of the two packages "wins".

So I would personally just do a *forced* installation of the broken package:

```bsh
# dpkg --force-overwrite -i /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd-sysv_241-7~deb10u6_amd64.deb
```

and after that restart the upgrade.

Please do note however, that the `--force-***` options of `dpkg` are usually considered dangerous and you shouldn't just blindly force things by copying shell snippets from the internet without understanding the implications.

#### Debian upgrades

OTOH, Debian spends a lot of blood , sweat and tears into making systems smoothly upgradable between Debian releases (e.g. *9* to *10*).
So why does it not work for you?

You should use `apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade between major releases (as this relaxes the resolver and allows to upgrade more complicated situtations than a simple `apt-get upgrade`).

You should also make sure to remove cruft from older installations.
E.g. your conflicting `sysvinit` package has a version number `2.88dsf-41+deb7u1` which indicates that it is from Debian **7**.
And indeed, there hasn't been a `sysvinit` package since Debian **8**.

So you should first make sure that you actually run a *Debian 9* system before you try to upgrade it to *Debian 10*.

Comment: Interesting answer, would `synaptic` be able to upgrade a Debian 9 install to Debian 10 after changing the all the sources (e.g. editing the sources.list through synaptic, then setting the preferred packages to `buster`) from `stretch` to `buster` in lieu of `apt-get dist-upgrade` ?

Comment: X.LINK, I don't know whether synaptic would work but I would question why you would want to deviate from Debian's instructions in the release notes for upgrading from 9 to 10. That being generally ```apt upgrade``` followed by ```apt dist-upgrade```. That's what they test, after all. OP's problem here was most likely caused by having a package from an older release still installed (stsvinit).

Comment: I may have left a landmine for myself as the machine was upgraded from 7 to 8 with a dist-upgrade some time ago and also had problems at that time. But, the system was working so I had no reason to search around. I actually solved by forcibly removing the sysvinit package that was still there and it worked.

Comment: Removing the ancient and obsolete `sysvinit` package should sort everything, and is probably the only thing necessary to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd-sysv_241-7~deb10u6_amd64.deb
```

followed by:

```
sudo apt install -f
```